# How to put a image in a span

Tags: css

I've made a toggle with the following CSS:

```css
.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 55px;
      height: 25px;
    }
    
    .switch input {display:none;}
    
    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      border-radius: 34px;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
      transform: translateX(30px);
    }
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Span needs to have an image inside, and when is checked another image, it should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Need to achieve this with CSS/React.

Comment: you could make it easier for people to help you with a fiddle where we can play around for you ;)

Comment: So what you have got there and what you are expecting is completely in two different worlds. Are you asking us to write the code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vrRQKW

Comment: Thanks a lot , is it possible to make it change the flag when checked?

Comment: @daeddadad Reload the page and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make something out:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI';
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 25px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 34px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/J4GQTYs.png');
  background-size: contain;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
  transform: translateX(30px);
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Q0iHcOX.png');
}

input:checked ~ .unchecked,
input ~ .unchecked,
input ~ .checked {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: none;
  top: 1px;
}

.unchecked {
  right: 5px;
}
.checked {
  left: 5px;
}
input:checked ~ .checked,
input ~ .unchecked {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  <span class="checked">FR</span>
  <span class="unchecked">EN</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Ah nice one, you posted it just before me. I should also make that the span is not selectable. Then it's perfect. :)

Comment: @JeroenE Ah... Sure... `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You can add:
`background-image: url(IMAGE);` for the image and `background-size: contain;` to make it visiable. Only using the `background-image` property won't work.

I added them to your example to: `slider:before {}` and `input:checked + .slider:before {}` to get the effect you're looking for. I've used different images as you stated as I couldn't find them so quickly. But of course you can just edit the url to the images you prefer (please don't use external images as I did in this example, add them to your server).

```css
.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 55px;
      height: 25px;
    }
    
    .switch input {display:none;}
    
    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      border-radius: 34px;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: .2s;
      background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/european-country-flags/83/italy-512.png');
      background-size: contain;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
      transform: translateX(30px);
      background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/european-country-flags/83/france-512.png');
      background-size: contain;
    }
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```